# mysql get more than one result from join query

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble returning more than one 'tag' from the 'catalog_tag' table when I perform a search query for a specific tag. If I do a search on 'catalog.catalog_id', I do get all the associated tags via the inner joins. Is there a way to grab the tags when searching for a specific tag?

Tables:

```
catalog table has: catalog_id|name|post_date

catalog_tag_relationship has: catalog_id|tag_id

catalog_tag has: tag_id|tag_name
```

SQL:

```
SELECT catalog_id, name, tag.tag_id, tag.tag_name 
FROM catalog   
INNER JOIN catalog_tag_relationship tagRel ON (tagRel.catalog_id=catalog.catalog_id)  
INNER JOIN catalog_tag tag ON (tagRel.catalog_tag_id=tag.tag_id)  
WHERE (tag.tag_name='dinosaurs')
```

Comment: `(tagRel.catalog_id=catalog.catalog_id)`?  Okay, you changed your post, but did it fix anything when you tested it?

Comment: I guess I am not understanding the question.  In your example query, it seems that you are only looking for a single tag with `tag_slug` = 'dinosaurs'.  The way your schema is set up, you should probably only have one tag with that `tag_slug` in the tag table, thought you might have multiple records in `catalog` associated with it.  Why do you expect to return more than one tag when you are only querying for one tag?

Comment: Sorry ebyrob, I fixed the query (was simplifying it down) for the post. @MikeBrant: A catalog item can have multiple tags (a dinosaur book can be have tags for: book, childrens, dinosaur,etc.). I want to do a search on the tag 'dinosaur' to retrieve any item and its relevant tags (including the one that I am searching on).

Comment: So, you want to get all the tags associated in each row of the result? (or set of rows)

Comment: @ebyrob Yes. I pretty much want to get all the tags if similar to if I swapped out the where statement to: WHERE (catalog.name='sbc')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised:

```
SELECT
  catalog.catalog_id,
  catalog.name,
  tag.tag_id,
  tag.tag_name
FROM (
  SELECT
    catalog.catalog_id as search_id
  FROM catalog
  INNER JOIN catalog_tag_relationship tagRel
          ON tagRel.catalog_id=catalog.catalog_id
  INNER JOIN catalog_tag tag ON tagRel.catalog_tag_id=tag.tag_id
  WHERE tag_name='dinosaurs'
  GROUP BY catalog.catalog_id
) AS searchList
INNER JOIN catalog ON catalog.catalog_id = search_id
INNER JOIN catalog_tag_relationship tagRel
        ON tagRel.catalog_id=catalog.catalog_id
INNER JOIN catalog_tag tag ON tagRel.catalog_tag_id=tag.tag_id
```

EDIT: This should return the same results as choosing a single list from the `catalog` table.

Step 1: Find list of catalog ID's matching search criteria.

Step 2: Fill in all catalog information for catalog ID's found in step 1.

This will return multiple rows per catalog entry, but only 1 row per unique catalog <-> tag mapping.  If you want one row per catalog you'd need `GROUP_CONCAT()` to see all the different tags for that catalog.

Comment: Wouldn't this yield multiple rows of the same catalog item? I guess another way to phrase the question is that I am looking to filter a result set of catalog items based on a tag name.

Comment: I don't think so?  I can make a set of test tables if it's not working as expected...  It may need a `GROUP BY`, but initially I was thinking it wouldn't (assuming tags are only related to catalogs once).

Comment: Thanks @ebyrob. I was wondering if there was a more modular approach to augmenting my first original query (subqueries or what not). I am trying to avoid a full rewrite of the larger more complex query if at all possible.

Comment: Well, if you want flexibility to change the where clause and do things like multiple tagnames combined with other criteria, then a subquery returning just a list of IDs is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @ebyrob. I ended up going with a subqury. Was just a bit rusty on the syntax.

Comment: @daxiang28 please post your solution so we can see it.  It makes the site a better resource.  Post it either as an answer or in the original question as an EDIT: section.